# Color excel cells using winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, excel, export-to-excel

Hi i want to export the color of a few buttons into excel the buttons represent a grid and are created dynamically.

The code I have seem to give me the name of the color and not the actual color of the cells when exported to Excel.

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{   
     for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
     {
          worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = (buttons[i][j].BackColor); 
     }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{   
     for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
     {
        Range range = worksheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1];
        range.Interior.Color = buttons[i][j].BackColor.ToArgb();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try assigning the back color?  = Color.Red

```
DataGridView1.Rows(4).DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
```

What i mean is if you are getting the name of the color assign it to the back color. not a good solution but consider it as a workaround